# Will I have trouble travelling to the UK as a vocal Extinction Rebellion member?

Tags: uk, australian-citizens

Extinction Rebellion (XR) [has been listed as terrorist organisation](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2020/jan/10/xr-extinction-rebellion-listed-extremist-ideology-police-prevent-scheme-guidance) in the UK. I am an Australian citizen with a passport who has been to the UK before, and an active member of XR Australia. Will I have an issue travelling there (primarily England) in the next 6 months?

Edit: In this case, please assume it holds up. This is entirely possible due to the [home secretary support](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/priti-patel-extinction-rebellion-police-extremism-list-counter-terror-prevent-a9281731.html)

Edit2: [more support to this designation](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2020/jan/17/greenpeace-included-with-neo-nazis-on-uk-counter-terror-list)

Comment: You can use the ePassport gates so you'll probably never speak to an immigration officer, even if you do, never give information you're not asked to give, I doubt they're going to ask you if you're part of XR

Comment: Note, they were listedas an *extremist* organisatiojn, not a *terrorist* one. The two may often overlap, but they are not considered the same thing, and there was no suggestion of them being a banned organisation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Mark has pointed out](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/152245/101), the police rowed back from listing XR as extremists, claiming that this was a mistake. However, it's important to note that the UK is extremely proactive in banning or refusing entry or visas to people considered undesirable.

At various times in the last few decades [anti-vivisectionists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Vlasak), [euthanasia activists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Nitschke), and numerous far right activists have been excluded from the UK, even in the absence of any criminal conviction.

Border officers have the power to refuse entry if they believe that an individual is "not conducive to the public good". I think it quite possible that if a border officer came to believe that you were travelling to the UK to participate in protests, especially those which [involve significant disruption](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2019/oct/14/police-ban-extinction-rebellion-protests-from-whole-of-london), they would refuse you entry. Your mere association with XR could cause the border officer to believe you were coming to the UK to protest.

Given the [heavy handed way in which the XR protests in London were policed](https://metro.co.uk/2019/10/16/under-priti-patels-rule-even-the-suffragettes-would-be-silenced-10927069/), the previous [use of anit-terror legislation against climate activists](https://www.independent.co.uk/voices/uk-mass-deportation-protesters-charged-terrorism-offences-chelmsford-court-dangerous-precedent-a8257211.html), and the right wing ideology of the current government and particularly the Home Secretary, it's entirely possible that a future XR protest could cause the government to treat XR activists harshly, and to attempt to exclude foreign activists from the UK.

I'm not saying that you need to be particularly concerned about your future travels to the UK, but I would avoid carrying any kind of XR material on your person when you enter the UK, to avoid discussing your activism with the border officer.

Comment: Not carrying XR material is a good idea, but may not be the end of things. If you have been vocal in your support of XR, and either your passport isn't biometric or e-gate entry is declined, the Border Officer's screen may well show your XR affiliation. You should be prepared to respond to questions about XR, your participation in XR matters, and your plans for this trip. Maybe this subject won't come up...but it'd be better to be prepared in case it does.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I don't see how the border officer's screen would identify XR affiliation.

Comment: I don't know either, but I'm unwilling to believe that it absolutely will *not* appear. Were I running that system, tidbits like "Connected to..." or "Appears with..." would be a useful adjunct to the officer's determination whether the individual may be entered or should be refused. Being prepared for this strikes me as prudent.

Answer (score 1):

Read the rest of the article. It was done allegedly in error.

> Counter-terrorism police confirmed it had been circulated to
>   “statutory partners” and had now been recalled. They said they now
>   accepted that the protest group was not extremist.

and later:

> In its first statement, CTPSE said: “This document was produced at a
>   local level to help our partners to spot the signs of vulnerability to
>   radicalisation. By including Extinction Rebellion in this document, it
>   gives the impression we consider them to be an extremist group, which
>   they are not. We will review the guidance to make this clear.”
>
> Later, after further inquiries from the Guardian, police said they
>   would recall the document.

Comment: On the other hand, the Home Secretary [apparently agrees with its inclusion](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/priti-patel-extinction-rebellion-police-extremism-list-counter-terror-prevent-a9281731.html).

Comment: See edit. I was unsure of the truth of the recall due to the Home Secretary statements that @MJeffryes also referenced. I don't think it's far-fetched to assume there is a possibility the designation will be upheld in some form

Comment: @MJeffryes "The home secretary accepted in an interview with LBC that XR was a protest group, not a terror threat, but stopped short of outright criticising the decision."  That's far cry from "agrees with its inclusion."

Comment: @phoog Maybe I'm reading between the lines a little too much, but her comments suggest she believes XR are a security risk.

Comment: @MJeffryes that is of course possible, but it seems to me rather more like an attempt to save face and/or to be supportive of her subordinates.